# Incorporate a timeout option when user click the upper right "x" on the window versus a button.

Tags: java, sql, swing, ms-access-2010

I built a Swing application that works with an MSAccess database. I have various buttons to click **when** clicked--they will disconnect and unlock the database.

Sadly, this is only in a perfect world where users will actually use those buttons and not the little red "x" on the upper right. When some users click that, the database stays locked with a file extension '.ldb' for those of you unfamiliar with MSAccess.

I need to avoid that. Is there any function that I can implement? Like a timeout? I looked up the

```
DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(10);
```

method, but that seems to be for login attempts. Is there something for my criteria?

Thanks.

PS: Sadly, i can't use any other database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sadly, this is only in a perfect world where users will actually use those buttons and not the little red "x" on the upper right.

See [Closing an Application.](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) You can create an Action that can be invoked when you use a button, menu item or when the user clicks on the "X" (close) button.

Answer (score 3):

Simply configure what happens when the "x" is pressed using a `WindowListener`.

This is done easily using two methods for the JFrame (`frame`, in the examples below) that displays everything:

```
1. frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE); // by default pressing the "x" will do nothing.
2. frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {  // However, when the "x" is pressed...
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {  // this method is called,
            ...  // and you write the body here to allow your program to respond appropriately
        }
    });
```

Eventually you'll want to call `frame.dispose()` to finally close the window.

You can implement additional methods in the body of the`WindowAdapter` inner class to respond to different window events... see the [WindowAdapter interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) for methods that can be implemented.

Comment: lol, duh.. didn't think of going about it that way. That's perfect, and simple to implement. So used to implementing my code templates with EXIT_ON_CLOSE that i totally didn't see that. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

1-  The KB5002099 patch deployed in Client computers recently, introduce a bug as a side effect of a security fix.

Here in the link  is the description of this patch -> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-office-2016-december-14-2021-kb5002099-10670400-427f-4819-8de6-abd11e73100b

Inside this description, you will find the Know issue of this update, and the solution (KB4484211) How to get and install the update
Databases on network share can't be accessed by multiple users in Office 2016 (KB4484211) (microsoft.com)
2-  Select download update for Office 2016, This update is available only for manual download and installation from the Microsoft Download Center.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/databases-on-network-share-can-t-be-accessed-by-multiple-users-in-office-2016-kb4484211-88a51f7f-f7dd-2d9c-0b96-b7fca0867a4f